# How do I solve cyclic dependency error between RDS and Secrets Manager stacks in AWS CDK v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I understand that sometimes order makes or breaks CloudFormation templates, but this one shouldn't be a problem, or at least it's not obvious to me why I'm getting this error:

> Error: 'DataPipelinePrototypeSecretStack' depends on
> 'DataPipelinePrototypeDatabaseStack' (DataPipelinePrototypeSecretStack
> -> DataPipelinePrototypeDatabaseStack/PrototypeDb1/Resource.Ref). Adding this dependency (DataPipelinePrototypeDatabaseStack ->
> DataPipelinePrototypeSecretStack/DataPipelinePrototypeMasterUserSecret/Resource.Ref)
> would create a cyclic reference.

I'm simply creating a secret in the SecretStack, entirely independent of RDS:

```js
export class SecretStack extends Stack {
    public readonly databaseMasterUserSecret: Secret;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        this.databaseMasterUserSecret = new Secret(this, "MasterUserSecret", {
            secretName: "pg-master-user-secret",
            generateSecretString: {
                secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({ username: "postgres" }),
                generateStringKey: "password",
                passwordLength: 16,
                excludePunctuation: true,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Then, in the DatabaseStack, creating the RDS instance:

```js
interface DatabaseStackProps extends StackProps {
    vpc: Vpc,
    securityGroup: SecurityGroup,
    secret: Secret
}

export class DatabaseStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: DatabaseStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const engine = DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({ version: PostgresEngineVersion.VER_15_4 });
        const instanceType = InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.T3, InstanceSize.MICRO);
        const port = 5432;
        const dbName = "dbname";

        const dbInstance = new DatabaseInstance(this, "TestDb1", {
            vpc: props.vpc,
            vpcSubnets: { subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED },
            instanceType,
            engine,
            port,
            securityGroups: [props.securityGroup],
            databaseName: dbName,
            credentials: Credentials.fromSecret(props.secret), //HERE...
            backupRetention: Duration.days(0),
            deleteAutomatedBackups: true,
            removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        });
    }
}
```

Here's how they're called in the entry point:

```js
const vpcStack = new VpcStack(app, "DataPipelinePrototypeVpc");
const secretStack = new SecretStack(app, "DataPipelinePrototypeSecretStack");
new DataBaseStack(app, "DataPipelinePrototypeDatabaseStack", {
    vpc: vpcStack.vpc,
    securityGroup: vpcStack.securityGroup,
    secret: secretStack.databaseMasterUserSecret
});
const lambdaStack = new LambdaStack(app, "DataPipelinePrototypeLambdaStack", {
    vpc: vpcStack.vpc,
    securityGroup: vpcStack.securityGroup,
    secret: secretStack.databaseMasterUserSecret
});
```

Flipping lambdaStack and DatabaseStack order didn't work.

When the secret was nested inside of the DatabaseStack like so, it worked just fine:

```js
export class DatabaseStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: DatabaseStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const engine = DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({ version: PostgresEngineVersion.VER_15_4 });
        const instanceType = InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.T3, InstanceSize.MICRO);
        const port = 5432;
        const dbName = "dbname";
        
        const secret = new Secret(this, "MasterUserSecret", {
            secretName: "pg-master-user-secret",
            description: "Database master user credentials",
            generateSecretString: {
                secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({ username: "postgres" }),
                generateStringKey: "password",
                passwordLength: 16,
                excludePunctuation: true,
            },
        });        

        const dbInstance = new DatabaseInstance(this, "TestDb1", {
            vpc: props.vpc,
            vpcSubnets: { subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED },
            instanceType,
            engine,
            port,
            securityGroups: [props.securityGroup],
            databaseName: dbName,
            credentials: Credentials.fromSecret(secret), //HERE...
            backupRetention: Duration.days(0),
            deleteAutomatedBackups: true,
            removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        });
    }
}
```

However, I need to add permissions to the Lambda (see entry point above), so I also need to pass the secret into the LambdaStack, so I'm able to retrieve the secret from within the Lambda code:

```js
interface LambdaStackProps extends StackProps {
    vpc: Vpc,
    securityGroup: SecurityGroup,
    secret: Secret
}

export class LambdaStack extends Stack {
    public readonly dataPipelineLambda: NodejsFunction;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: LambdaStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        this.dataPipelineLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "Lambda", {
            functionName: "dataPipelineHandler",
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
            handler: "handler",
            entry: "./service/handler.ts"
        });
        this.dataPipelineLambda.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
            resources: [props.secret.secretArn],
            actions: [
                "ssm:Get*"
            ]
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone has a better answer, I was able to manually extract the `credentials` values in the `DatabaseInstance` to make it work:

```js
new DatabaseInstance(this, "PrototypeDb1", {
    ///...etc...
    credentials: {
        username: props.secret.secretValueFromJson("username").unsafeUnwrap().toString(),
        password: props.secret.secretValueFromJson("password")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the secret in the parent stack.

```
const vpcStack = new VpcStack(app, "DataPipelinePrototypeVpc");

const secret = new Secret(this, "MasterUserSecret", {
    secretName: "pg-master-user-secret",
    generateSecretString: {
        secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({ username: "postgres" }),
        generateStringKey: "password",
        passwordLength: 16,
        excludePunctuation: true,
    },
});

new DataBaseStack(app, "DataPipelinePrototypeDatabaseStack", {
    vpc: vpcStack.vpc,
    securityGroup: vpcStack.securityGroup,
    secret
});
const lambdaStack = new LambdaStack(app, "DataPipelinePrototypeLambdaStack", {
    vpc: vpcStack.vpc,
    securityGroup: vpcStack.securityGroup,
    secret
});
```

Comment: Nice, I like the simple solutions. I'm sure this works, but I'd ideally keep all stacks separate for that clean separation of concerns. This could get messy if the solution requires more than a couple secrets - and this one could. I'd also like to understand why it's creating a circular reference when there sincerely isn't one - you can see I'm doing the exact same thing w/ the VPC and it's not complaining about that in any way. Bug?

Comment: @TsarBomba You could create the secrets inside the DataBaseStack and 1) expose them or their ARN as public variables or 2) use CfnOutput to export their ARNs to be imported in other stacks. Not sure about the circular dependency. Have you tried adding an explicit dependency with `dbStack.addDependency(secretStack)`?

Answer (score 0):

What you also can do is create the secret (or use `credentials: rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('master')`) in the Database Stack and export the auto created secret and use that one in the Lambda Stack.